# Angular param query not working with express API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Good afternoon guys! I am getting undefined when I query localhost/post-number-2. However, when I access the api I can retrieve the correct JSON object - so when I search for localhost/api/articles/post-number-2 the API will do it's job and print back the information. I am unsure why it is not working with the angular routes. Here is the routing for the slug.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/:slug', {
        templateUrl: 'views/article.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

This is my controller. I am trying to make it so that thumbnails are displayed normally and if there is a param req display whole article queried.

```
    angular.module('clientApp')  
      .controller('MainCtrl', ['$http','$routeParams', function ($http, $routeParams) {

        var scope = this;


        if($routeParams.slug){
          var slug = $routeParams.slug;


          var req = $http.get('/api/articles/' + slug);

          req.then(function (res) {
            scope.article_slug = res.data.article;
            console.log(res.data.article);
          });
          req.catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });

      } else {

        var req1 = $http.get('/api/articles');  

        req1.then(function (res) {
          scope.articles = res.data.articles;
        });
        req1.catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });

      }
        scope.awesomeThings = [
          'HTML5 Boilerplate',
          'AngularJS',
          'Karma'
        ];
      }]);
```

And finally my route in express - however since the api call works I don't think this is the problem.

```
    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
        db.articles.find(function(err, articles){
            if(err){
              res.send(err);
            } 
              res.json({articles: articles});  
          }

    )});

    router.get('/:slug', function(req, res, next){
      console.log(req.params.slug); 
      db.articles.findOne({slug: req.params.slug}, function(err, article){

        if(err){
          res.send(err);
        } 
          res.json(article);

      }
    )});
```

Any insight would be much appreciated! Enjoy the rest of your day :D

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: In my server I just logged what happened when I searched localhost/post-numer-2 and it is recieving the param and it is finding the correct object. So the probelm is definitely in the req.then function - all it is saying that it is undefined when I try to log it to the console

Comment: did you try to log the entire res object (not res.data.article)? maybe it does not contain the attributes you think it contains

Comment: That did it - forgot that the JSON object would return just a single object. Not {articles: [{objects}]} - just had to get rid of the .articles! Much thanks!